# Gazebo Plugin Tutorial error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Gazebo with ROS Electric on Ubuntu 10.04 and I have been trying to do the Plugin tutorial.

At Step 6, after trying roslaunch, I get the following error:

`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gazebo/gui]: Cannot locate node of type [gui] in package [gazebo]`

tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreAdaptor.cc:187 : Exception: Ogre TextureManager initialization failed.  Please double check your world file or glx support from your gpu / gpu driver, thank you.

/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:309 : Exception: Failed to Initialize the Rendering engine subsystem
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreAdaptor.cc:187 : Exception: Ogre TextureManager initialization failed.  Please double check your world file or glx support from your gpu / gpu driver, thank you.

Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:309 : Exception: Failed to Initialize the Rendering engine subsystem
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.15/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreAdaptor.cc:187 : Exception: Ogre TextureManager initialization failed.  Please double check your world file or glx support from your gpu / gpu driver, thank you.

The world file I am using is straight from the tutorial. My graphics card is an ATI Radeon HD 4200, which is on Gazebo's list of working cards. Could this be an issue with paths?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63371/gazebo-plugin-tutorial-error/) by [Ros Qwertyuiop](https://answers.ros.org/users/4954/ros-qwertyuiop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not for your ROS version but a possible solution:
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1125/after-updating-gazebo-to-13-under-groovy-i-get-an/

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1